# Does hallow spread through sand background?

Tags: terraria

I noticed that in my desert the the background/wall changes its color and is expanded beyond the converted sand blocks.

Does that mean that the hallow background can infect blocks even if no solid blocks are in range of other hallow solid blocks?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Corruption, Crimson, and Hallow can spread to background walls from solid blocks, but not from background walls to solid blocks. So no, hallow backgrounds are perfectly safe.

Comment: Unless it has changed recently, background walls can be changed, but not change other blocks. (I ended up with an extensive test case of this on one of my early worlds. It was corruption rather than Hallow though. I mean I had Hallow, but it wasn't the part that made me notice the change.)

Comment: @Nick Yeah, perhaps I didn't word that perfectly but you're correct.

Comment: @Nick Or rather, I was totally wrong on that. Oops.

Comment: does that mean that the hollow background spreads out on the other background or does ot stop on the 6 (wanted to be on the safe side) block wide gaps i made?

Comment: @vlad_tepesch It spreads from solid blocks to backgrounds, but not from backgrounds to backgrounds or from backgrounds to solid blocks.

Comment: i added a picture. the background is spreaded far more than 3 blocks away from the next converted

Answer (score -5):

Yes, but this only happens when you defeat the Wall of Flesh. If you want to prevent it from spreading you cane make deep holes on both sides of the corruption. The corruption is the only area that starts to spread after you beat the wall of flesh.

Comment: sorry but your answer is factually incorrect